# PDF font subsetting and subset merging in Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a part in my code where I am programatically filling out PDF forms using iText Java based on user-entered data, and then I concat a number of such PDFs into one using iText again.

The PDF forms that are getting merged can be (and usually are) different.

The resulting PDF is way too large - looking at it, 98% of the space is taken by fonts.

The way I understand it, what happens is that the individual PDF forms have different font subsets, so when I merge them, I get massive amount of duplicate glyphs, except that the subsets are not identical, so I can't get rid of them without merging the subsets.

The other problem is that the PDF forms themselves might not even contain subsets, but heavily packed fonts that have 2000+ glyphs, so even if I manage to leave only one instance of that font in the PDF, that still can be many megabytes. Hence it seems that I need to be able to 1) create and 2) merge existing font subsets.

The quirk is that I do not control neither the PDF forms (that are being filled out) nor their number, nor the order in which they are concatenated, so it is not possible to solve this by controlling what kind of fonts are embedded in them.

Adobe Acrobat can of course solve such a problem - it can create and also merge font subsets - but I need a programatic, server-side solution. According to google hits, iText cannot do this. Is there another library that I could use (or anything else I can do)?

Comment: There are different ways to achieve what you want. Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YwDME0Fl1c) to find out an alternative way. [FlattenMerge1](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/FillFlattenMerge1) is obviously the wrong way. I assume that you are using [FillFlattenMerge2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/FillFlattenMerge2), but it's [FillFlattenMerge3](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/FillFlattenMerge3) that  will solve your problem.

Comment: I watched the 40+ mins video, but I am unclear how option 3 would solve my problem. Like I wrote in the question, the problem is that I have different font subsets, and you yourself stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20698809/1824548 that iText cannot merge them...?

Comment: Instead of filling out each form one by one, in which case iText creates a *different subset* for every single form. Fill out all the forms in the same document, in which case iText creates only *a single subset* for the complete bundle of forms. That is what `FillFlattenMerge3` is about, isn't it?

Comment: Sure, but what about fonts that are already in the different PDF forms? Will the huge embedded ones be subsetted and the already subsetted ones merged? As far as the space audit tells me, they are the root cause of the problem - and I am not using an additional font to fill the form anyway, but the one that the field defines (not sure if subsetting happens then too?).

Comment: I made the wrong assumption that the forms weren't different. I thought that you were talking about receiving a single template that needed to be filled out many times and of which the different instances then needed to be concatenated. One of our customers had a similar problem once. As it turned out, the main problem indeed concerned the original forms: they were bloated and manually removing MBytes of fonts that weren't needed, solved the problem. Obviously, you can only do that if you're confronted with a limited number of different forms.

Comment: Added a clarification to the question. The problem is still there then - I need a framework that can merge/create font subsets in existing PDFs.

Comment: Please don't discuss in comments what could be written as (part of) proper answers. Otherwise you risk that this question harvests enough "close" votes (by people who have no interest at all in `[pdf]`-related questions) to make it disappear...