# SSRS 2012 Embed Full Fonts During PDF Rendering

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting-services, itext, ssrs-2012

I have a situation where we have maybe 100 reports generated by SSRS and exported to PDF. These 100 reports are then merged together into 1 large PDF for distribution (and before anyone recommends it, the general process isn't changing...we will continue to receive multiple individual PDF files for the foreseeable future).

The size of the merged PDF is quite large (I am using iTextSharp and PdfSmartCopy to merge for those that are interested). Code is below in case someone can improve upon it.

```
    private void MergePDF()
    { 
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfSmartCopy pdf = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, stream);
            doc.Open();

            files.OrderBy(o => o.GetOrder()).ToList().ForEach(file =>
            {
                pdf.AddDocument(new PdfReader(file.AcquireFile()));
            });

            mergedStream = new MemoryStream(stream.GetBuffer());

            if (doc != null) doc.Close();
        }

        mergedFile = new EMMAFilePDF();
        mergedFile.SetStream(mergedStream);
    }
```

I have narrowed the issue down to font subsets. [It appears SSRS will embed a font subset for each report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255291.aspx#Anchor_0). And iTextSharp, justifiably, [cannot merge embedded font subsets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20698809/150684).

Using Acrobat Pro I can clean some of this up and reduce the file size but I am attempting to fully automate the process and this font subset issue appears to be the last piece.

**Which brings me to the core question here: is anyone aware of a way to force SSRS to embed the full font instead of a font subset? If so then iTextSharp can de-dup the full fonts when merging, resulting in a much smaller final PDF size.**

**Or, is there a tool (non-free is acceptable) that can properly merge font subsets?**